# "Error: unable to open database file" for GROUP BY query

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

I have a python script which creates a sqlite database out of some external data. This works fine. But everytime I execute a GROUP BY query on this database, I get an "Error: unable to open database file". Normal SELECT queries work.

This is an issue for both, the sqlite3 library of python and the sqlite3 cli binary:

```
sqlite> SELECT count(*) FROM REC;
count(*)
----------
528489
sqlite> SELECT count(*) FROM REC GROUP BY VERSION;
Error: unable to open database file
sqlite>
```

I know that these errors are typically permission errors (I have read all questions which I could find on this topic on StackOverflow), but I'm quite sure it is not in my case:

1. I'm talking about a readily created database and read requests
2. I checked the permissions: Both the file and its containing folders have write permissions set
3. I can even write to the database: Creating a new table is no problem.
4. The device is not full, it got plenty of space.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file have you checked ownership on the directory the sqlite file is in? If the file is somewhere outside your $HOME, try moving it to your $HOME and see if the problem goes away. If it does, then it's a permissions/ownership issue.

Comment: From your session it seems you have the same problem *outside* of python, using just the `sqlite3` command line utility.

Comment: As I tried to make clear: It is not a permission problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that your process has access to the TEMP directory.

From the [SQLite's Use Of Temporary Disk Files](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) documentation:

> SQLite may make use of transient indices to implement SQL language
>   features such as:
>
> - An ORDER BY or GROUP BY clause
> - The DISTINCT keyword in an aggregate query
> - Compound SELECT statements joined by UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT
>
> Each transient index is stored in its own temporary file. The
>   temporary file for a transient index is automatically deleted at the
>   end of the statement that uses it.

You probably can verify if temporary storage is the problem by setting the [`temp_store` pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store) to `MEMORY`:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
```

to tell SQLite to keep the transient index for the `GROUP BY` clause in memory.

Alternatively, create an explicit index on the column you are grouping by to prevent the transient index from being created.

Comment: Thanks, that brought me closer to the issue, it realy seems a problem with the temp directory. I'm not sure where the temp directory resides which sqlite3 uses as it is in a cygwin environment.

Comment: You'd have to re-compile SQLite itself, setting the [`SQLITE_TEMP_STORE` compilation option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#temp_store).

Comment: I was having the `unable to open database` when trying to create an index; the funny thing is that I had just created another index in another column of the same table and it worked fine. It's a problem different from the OP, but your solution of setting `temp_store = memory` worked fine for me, many thanks.